# C++ std::atomic for user defined data types

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am unable to understand and write up a code related to below Atomic Library functionality for user defined data type:

> std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak,
> std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong

```
bool compare_exchange_weak( T& expected, T desired,
                            std::memory_order success,
                            std::memory_order failure );

bool compare_exchange_strong( T& expected, T desired,
                              std::memory_order success,
                              std::memory_order failure );
```

So if I have below trivial class how can I use compare_exchange_weak / compare_exchange_strong Atomic library methods on that trivial class?

```
class A
{
public:
    void Show()
    {
        std::cout << "Called\n";
    }
};
```

I am unsure what expected / desired values we should set in the method for user defined datatype - class A for example?

Comment: is there any reason you want to use that two methods? You can use an `std::atomic` without using those two methods. I find it a bit puzzling that you first pick the methods and ask how to use them instead of saying what you want to do with the atomic (and then see if you can make use of those two methods).

Comment: ...moreover `A` has no data, zero members, its only method needs no synchronization. There is no need to do something atomically with `A`

Comment: Object of given class A has only one byte of padding, not available from programmer. The compare_exchange functions just compare bits of that padding. Feels rather pointless to start learning something like that, better find a book like that https://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770

Comment: Actually I wanted to know the compare_exchange_strong compares with for user defined data type - in this case which A's method will it invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has no data, hence there is no need to use `std::atomic<A>`. If you want to know how to use `std::atomic` with UDT, You may add a member data and then use the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

class A
{
public:
    int a;
    void Show()
    {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }
};

int main( ) {
    A a1{1};
    A a2{2};
    std::atomic<A> atomicA{a1};
    atomicA.load().Show();//the original atomicA
    atomicA.compare_exchange_strong(a2, A{2});// this makes no change
    atomicA.load().Show();
    atomicA.compare_exchange_strong(a1, A{2});//this changes atomicA
    atomicA.load().Show();

}
```

Note that not all UDT can gain a real atomic behavior (it may be achieved using locks). to make sure that your atomic has a real atomic behavior you can use `atomicA.is_lock_free()`.

Comment: Thanks but then what does compare_exchange_strong compares with - which A's method will it invoke?

Comment: @Programmer it compares the bit representation of the objects until c++20. and will compare the value rep. using == defined operator since c++20.

Comment: BTW what does A a1{1}; means when A does not have constructor that accepts an integer? I tried A a1; std::atomic<A> atm{ a1 }; but it gave me below error :Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'a1' used Atomic Operations

Comment: @Programmer https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization